Duplicate main symbol in CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
I have a QT app with CMakeLists.txt project file that successfully builds for Windows and Android, but when I tried to build it for MacOS I got the following linker error:
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    /Users/admin/dev/repos/tradeclient/src/TradeClient/build/Desktop_x86_darwin_generic_mach_o_64bit/build/TradeClient.build/RelWithDebInfo/Objects-normal/x86_64/CMakeCXXCompilerId.o
    /Users/admin/dev/repos/tradeclient/src/TradeClient/build/Desktop_x86_darwin_generic_mach_o_64bit/build/TradeClient.build/RelWithDebInfo/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbols
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Where TradeClient is my app and Desktop_x86_darwin_generic_mach_o_64bit is the configuration.
By doing a simple text search I found ./CMakeFiles/3.29.2/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp in build directory containing its own main:
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int require = 0;
  require += info_compiler[argc];
  require += info_platform[argc];
  require += info_arch[argc];
#ifdef COMPILER_VERSION_MAJOR
  require += info_version[argc];
#endif
#ifdef COMPILER_VERSION_INTERNAL
  require += info_version_internal[argc];
#endif
#ifdef SIMULATE_ID
  require += info_simulate[argc];
#endif
#ifdef SIMULATE_VERSION_MAJOR
  require += info_simulate_version[argc];
#endif
#if defined(__CRAYXT_COMPUTE_LINUX_TARGET)
  require += info_cray[argc];
#endif
  require += info_language_standard_default[argc];
  require += info_language_extensions_default[argc];
  (void)argv;
  return require;
}

obviously generated by CMake.
What is this main for? And why is it included to the project?
I compile the project with QT Creator 13 that runs CMake as follows:
Configuring with XCode generator:
[cmake] Running /opt/local/bin/cmake -S /Users/admin/dev/repos/tradeclient/src/TradeClient -B /Users/admin/dev/repos/tradeclient/src/TradeClient/build/Desktop_x86_darwin_generic_mach_o_64bit -DCMAKE_GENERATOR:STRING=Xcode -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE_BEFORE:FILEPATH=/Users/admin/dev/repos/tradeclient/src/TradeClient/build/Desktop_x86_darwin_generic_mach_o_64bit/.qtc/package-manager/auto-setup.cmake -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/Users/admin/dev/libs/QT6/release/MacOs/bin/qmake6 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=/Users/admin/dev/libs/QT6/release/MacOs -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT:STRING= in /Users/admin/dev/repos/tradeclient/src/TradeClient/build/Desktop_x86_darwin_generic_mach_o_64bit.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
[cmake] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
[cmake] -- Found Threads: TRUE
[cmake] -- Found ZLIB: /opt/local/lib/libz.dylib (found version "1.3.1")
[cmake] -- Found WrapSystemZLIB: TRUE
[cmake] -- Using system ZLIB.
[cmake] -- Found WrapZLIB: TRUE
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC - Success
[cmake] -- Found WrapAtomic: TRUE
[cmake] -- Looking for backtrace
[cmake] -- Looking for backtrace - found
[cmake] -- backtrace facility detected in default set of libraries
[cmake] -- Found Backtrace: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/usr/include
[cmake] -- Using Qt bundled PCRE2.
[cmake] -- Found WrapPCRE2: TRUE
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_GETTIME
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_GETTIME - Success
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_SHM_OPEN_SHM_UNLINK
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_SHM_OPEN_SHM_UNLINK - Success
[cmake] -- Found WrapRt: TRUE
[cmake] -- Found OpenGL: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
[cmake] -- Found WrapOpenGL: TRUE
[cmake] -- Using Qt bundled PNG.
[cmake] -- Found WrapPNG: TRUE
[cmake] -- Using Qt bundled Harfbuzz.
[cmake] -- Found WrapHarfbuzz: TRUE
[cmake] -- Using Qt bundled Freetype.
[cmake] -- Found WrapFreetype: TRUE
[cmake] -- Using Qt bundled Jpeg.
[cmake] -- Found WrapJpeg: TRUE
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_LIBRESOLV_FUNCTIONS
[cmake] -- Performing Test HAVE_LIBRESOLV_FUNCTIONS - Success
[cmake] -- Found WrapResolv: TRUE
[cmake] -- Found GSSAPI: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework
[cmake] -- Found AVFoundation: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework
[cmake] -- Found OpenSSL: /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib (found version "3.2.1") found components: Crypto SSL
[cmake] OpenSSL include: /opt/local/include
[cmake] Enabling 128 bit integer support.
[cmake] Using home made implementation of std::jthread.
[cmake] CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION: 23.4.0
[cmake] Posix native platform.
[cmake] AWL_PLATFORM_DIR: ../../lib/Awl/Platforms/Posix
[cmake] Applying the workaround for QT Creator.
[cmake] Detected locale "C" with character encoding "US-ASCII", which is not UTF-8.
[cmake] Qt depends on a UTF-8 locale, and has switched to "UTF-8" instead.
[cmake] If this causes problems, reconfigure your locale. See the locale(1) manual
[cmake] for more information.
[cmake] -- Configuring done (19.0s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /Users/admin/dev/repos/tradeclient/src/TradeClient/build/Desktop_x86_darwin_generic_mach_o_64bit
[cmake] 
[cmake] Elapsed time: 00:20.

Building:
09:31:34: Running steps for project TradeClient...
09:31:34: Starting: "/opt/local/bin/cmake" --build /Users/admin/dev/repos/tradeclient/src/TradeClient/build/Desktop_x86_darwin_generic_mach_o_64bit --target ALL_BUILD --config RelWithDebInfo


Please show your CMakeLists.txt. I would guess you add your sources with GLOB or similar and since you're building inside the source directory (for unkown reasons) the build dir is also searched for cpp files and the cmake compile test file is picked up for your project. Do an out-of-source build and don't use GLOB to add your source files.

@chehrlic yes, it is GLOB_RECURSE, I have a lot of them.  If I configure build directory outside of the sources directory the build succeeds.
